# Should databases be separated based on size and load?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'm developing a web backend with two modules. One handles a relatively small amount of data that doesn't change often. The other handles real-time data that's constantly being dumped into the database and never gets changed or deleted. I'm not sure whether to have separate databases for each module or just one.

The data between the modules is interconnected quite a bit, so it's a lot more convenient to have it in a single database.

But anything fails, I need the first database to be available for reads as soon as possible, and the second one can wait.

Also I'm not sure how much performance impact the constantly growing large database would have on the first one.

I'd like to make dumps of the data available to public, and I don't want users downloading gigabytes that they don't need.

And if I decide to use a single one, how easy is it to separate them later? I use Postgres, btw.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "database"?  Are you referring to separate database engines or are you referring to separate databases within the same database engine?  If you're going to have separate database engines, they should be on separate database engine computers.

Comment: There's no such thing as "best" in engineering unless *you* define it. And then, how are you stuck deciding? Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design & all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a website with its content being the first DB, and some kind of analytics being the second DB.

It makes sense to separate those physically (as in on different servers). Especially if one of those is required to be available as much as possible. Separating mission critical parts from something not that important is a good design. Also, smaller DB means shorter recovery times from a backup, if such need to arise.

For the data that is interconnected, if you need remote lookup from one DB into another, [Foreign Data Wrappers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) may help.